# French sports metaphors

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, sport

I'm looking for French sports metaphors/sayings. For example, "hit it out of the park" for American/baseball is widely used outside of sports. Another example is "come out fighting" for boxing. Are there similar sports metaphors/sayings in common usage?

Answer (score 6):

There are many such expressions:

- *Botter en touche* (rugby)
- *Carton rouge* (football a.k.a. soccer)
- *Être dans les starting-blocks* (sprints)
- *Être hors-jeu* (football, rugby)
- *Être K.O.* (boxing)
- *Être le nez dans le guidon* (cycling)
- *Faire un faux départ* (track)
- *Faire un parcours sans faute* (equestrian show jumping)
- *Les doigts dans le nez* (horse racing)
- *Il n'y a pas photo* (horse racing)
- *Jeter l'éponge* (boxing)
- *La balle est dans leur camp* (football, rugby)
- *La dernière ligne droite* (horse racing)
- *Marquer à la culotte* (football, rugby)
- *Mettre en plein dans le mille* (archery)
- *Passer le relais* (track relays)
- *Renvoyer quelqu'un dans ses cordes* (boxing)
- *Rester sur le banc de touche* (football)
- *Se faire coiffer sur le poteau* (horse racing)
- *Tenir la corde* (horse racing)
- ...

Comment: Nice list, and as you say there are many more, but two of my favorites (heard/used together nearly as often as "Tribu de Dana" during the glorious Summer of '98 and [apparently coming from the "Sport of Kings"](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/les-doigts-dans-le-nez.php)) are "[gagner/avoir gagné] les doigts dans le nez" and its more "colorful" variation "[perdre/avoir perdu] les doigts dans le cul!"

Comment: @PapaPoule Indeed, thanks! That one and a similar one added to the list.

Comment: J'apprends au passage que "les doigts dans le nez" vient de l'équitation ! Il y a aussi "*mouiller le maillot*", je ne sais pas si ça vient d'un sport en particulier ou si c'est général.

Comment: Moi qui pensais que l'on pouvait utiliser finger in the nose/in the ass en anglais :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Il semble que mouiller le maillot d'abord ait suivi un cheminement inverse : Mouiller sa chemise (travailler dur, vocabulaire ouvrier) -> mouiller la chemise/mouiller le maillot (football, influence de l'occitan, comme tomber la chemise), mais il est vrai que l'expression s'élargit et s'étend à nouveau vers d'autres contextes non sportifs.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a une différence très marquée entre les expressions sportives européennes (très axées ici sur le vélo, le football et, je crois, le rugby...) et québécoises, généralement influencées par [le hockey](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/dis-tu-dis-langue-quebecoise-francais-canada/).

Une fraction non négligeable des exemple de jlliagre sont rares, voire pratiquement inconnus au Québec.

Comment: L'article est intéressant, la réflexion à propos de _vite sur ses patins_ est amusante, la personne de France semble (elle devine _se préparer vite_) avoir compris que la personne était rapidement prête à patiner, qu'elle avait rapidement chaussé ses patins alors que l'expression réfère au déplacement sur les patins, à la rapidité (d'esprit)... Un exemple serait bien. Merci !