# La Cour « avait botté en touche pour [...] pour écarter des plaintes [...] » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, prépositions, lexique, sport

> Même si cette pratique [ le [*gerrymandering*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering) ] est très critiquée, la Cour suprême n'a pour
>   l'instant jamais jugé qu'elle violait la Constitution. En juin, elle
>   avait **botté en touche pour**  des raisons procédurales **pour**
>   écarter des plaintes portées par des électeurs du Wisconsin et du
>   Maryland.
>
> [ « [La Cour suprême des États-Unis se saisit de découpages électoraux
>   partisans](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/04/01-5209996-la-cour-supreme-des-etats-unis-se-saisit-de-decoupages-electoraux-partisans.php) » ds. La presse via l'AFP, je souligne ]

Évidemment que [*botter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/botter) c'est familièrement et par métonymie donner un coup de pied, plus particulièrement au *ballon* dans le domaine sportif. On a la *remise en [touche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/touche)* pour remettre le ballon en jeu à la ligne de touche etc. Ici, c'est la Cour suprême qui avait *botté en touche pour... pour...*. Je comprends aussi mal le sens que la syntaxe de cette phrase ; j'en comprends généralement qu'elle a écarté des plaintes pour des raisons procédurales et je ne vois pas quelle nuance ajouterait l'expression en question...

- Que signifie ici que la Cour ait *botté en touche* et qu'est-ce qui
  est *botté en touche* ?
- Pourquoi on a deux fois la préposition [*pour*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour) ici ?
- Est-ce usuel et fréquent de retrouver cette analogie sportive dans un texte d'information sur la politique et le droit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Que signifie ici que la Cour ait botté en touche et qu'est-ce qui est botté en touche ?

C'est une métaphore. Au sens propre, [botter en touche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/botter_en_touche) au rugby est une action de jeu qui consiste à envoyer le ballon le plus loin possible en touche pour écarter le danger immédiat. Par ce geste, on éloigne le risque d'une confrontation directe avec l'équipe adverse, d'une certaine manière on refuse le combat en donnant le ballon à l'adversaire.

Ici, au sens figuré, la cour suprême a refusé de prendre position face aux plaintes exprimées par des électeurs à propos d'une pratique qu'ils jugeaient contraire à la constitution.

> Pourquoi on a deux fois la préposition pour ici ?

La première fois pour expliquer la méthode utilisée pour refuser de statuer (on invoque des raisons procédurales), la deuxième fois pour expliquer pourquoi elle l'a fait (pour écarter les plaintes, pour ne pas avoir à se prononcer).

> Est-ce usuel et fréquent de retrouver cette analogie sportive dans un texte d'information sur la politique et le droit ?

Oui. Les métaphores sportives sont courantes dans la presse et ce depuis longtemps. En Europe, les sports sont semble-t-il plus variés (course hippique, football, rugby, etc.) alors qu'au Canada, c'est le hockey qui est le principal pourvoyeur d'expressions de ce type. Celle-ci a déjà été évoquée [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29474/french-sports-metaphors/29475#29475).

Comment: Action défensive au rugby ? Hmmm... tu as joué dans une équipe dont les avants étaient un peu faiblards ? Non! Sans blague! Action offensive ou défensive... cela dépend vraiment du rapport des forces en présence. Si l'ouvreur ou l'arrière a confiance que sa ligne d'avant est plus forte que celle de l'adversaire, c'est définitivement l'action offensive la plus efficace. Un ex 15!

Comment: @aCOSwt Je retire l'adjectif. L'action n'est pas forcément défensive, c'est vrai.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Il serait bien sûr préférable de connaitre l'action précise à laquelle correspond ce «  botté en touche », mais s'il ne s'agit que d'une compréhension générale il me semble ne pas y avoir d'autre possibilité que de concevoir le travail habituel de la cour comme étant interrompu, de la même manière que dans le jeu, où les conditions étant désavantageuses, le joueur trouve plus profitable de forcer un arrêt et de cette façon pouvoir repartir (à la remise en jeu) sur une donne plus favorable. Je ne pense pas qu'il faille pousser l'analogie trop loin et exiger un ballon ; il est question d'une interaction habituelle au cours de laquelle la Cour cherche à parvenir à ses fins et le déroulement de cette interaction normale c'est le jeu dans lequel la Cour étant l'une des équipes (il n'est même pas nécessaire de pousser l'analogie jusqu'à faire de la Cour un simple joueur dans une équipe) et diverse organisations l'équipe adverse ; arrêter cette interaction normale, le dialogue préliminaire à la décision de la Court pour ainsi dire (c'est à dire le ballon si l'on veut), c'est ce que « botter en touche » décrit ; le dialogue (ballon) est éliminé de l'interaction (jeu), ce qui arrête celle-ci pendant un certain temps.

2/ J'aurais tendance à concevoir l'ensemble « des raisons procédurales pour écarter des plaintes portées par des électeurs du Wisconsin et du Maryland » comme un groupe nominal ; selon ce point de vue je ne crois pas que « les plaintes soient écartées parce qu'il y aurait des raisons procédurales forçant cette action » ; je pense que l'arrêt momentané est exigé pour satisfaire à des raisons procédurales qui vont permettre d'écarter des plaintes. Deux fois la préposition « pour » s'explique assez bien une fois que l'on accepte cette idée de syntagme qui s'impose selon un modèle inéluctable. (Exemple simple : Un dernier déplacement dans la grange **pour** une échelle **pour** monter sur le toit).

3/ Il me semble que cette façon imagée de s'exprimer est un fait de la fin du XXe siècle et du début du XXIe que l'on constate dans la presse tout au moins en ce qui concerne la politique ; la presse dans ce domaine aurait jusqu'alors conservé un ton factuel. Je ne peut cependant  pas déterminer de fréquence selon laquelle cette analogie particulière serait employée ; il y a une évidence qu'il en existe un certain nombre d'occurrence dans le domaine politique et le domaine juridique ;cette évidence est fournie par [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/botter+en+touche).

Voici les deux exemples que l'on trouve à la référence mentionnée;

> Le rapporteur de la commission juridique propose de botter en touche en renvoyant le débat.
>
> Il ne s'agit en aucun cas pour moi de botter en touche mais de la seule façon d'exprimer mon avis sur le signal contradictoire qu'envoie aujourd'hui notre Parlement.